# python downloading data (urllib, urllib2)

Tags: python, html, mp3, urllib2, urllib

I have a link like [this](http://www23.zippyshare.com/d/44123087/497548/Lil%20Wayne%20ft.%20Eminem%20-%20Drop%20The%20World.mp3), direct to a mp3 file. So when I put it in my browser, basically asks me if I want to download the file, however when I do the same thing with python by the following code :

```
> data = urllib2.urlopen("http://www23.zippyshare.com/d/44123087/497548/Lil%20Wayne%20ft.%20Eminem%20-%20Drop%20The%20World.mp3".read())
```

I will redirected to another link like this. Therefore, instead of the MP3 data, I am getting the html code for

> 'http://www23.zippyshare.com/v/44123087/file.html'

any ideas ?
thanks

Comment: sh0w u5 t3h c0d3z, l33t h4x0R. you're probably not handling cookies?

Comment: im using urllib2 which should automatically handle cookies, im not too sure though !

Comment: it does, but it takes a little bit of effort. you at least have to tell it that's what you want. do a little googling for urllib2 cookielib

Comment: just tried a the code one of the guys posted and that did not work, thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

urllib2 handles redirection transparently. You might want to see what the server is actually doing when it is presenting such a redirection as well allowing you to download. You might want to [subclass](http://uthcode.sarovar.org/pycon2010/web.html) the redirect handler and see which property of the header is giving you the url and use urlretrieve to download that.

Setting the cookies, trying explicitly might be a good try as well.

```
import cookielib, urllib2
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.open('yourmp3filelink')
```

Comment: i tried the code, that did not work, i will give the subclass a shot

Comment: Also, see what curl does when you give the url.

Answer (score 0):

Your link redirects to an HTML webpage, most likely because your download request is timing out. That's often how these download websites work: you never get a static link to the download, only a temporarily assigned link.

My guess is that there's no way to get that static link using that website. You'd have to know where that file was *actually* coming from.

So no, nothing is wrong with your python code; just your sources.

Comment: @patrick perini but why does it work when im using my browser ? that is the part that i dont understand !!

Comment: Because you've visited the website and that temporarily assigned link is still good for you. Once your session/cookie (whatever the case may be) expires, the link will stop working. Technically, you can do the same thing with python (by juggling the cookies) but it won't be reliable, repeatable, expandable, or portable. You're better off just clicking the link.

Comment: i got the link 2 hours ago and it works fine on all my browsers (firefox, chrome and explorer) but it does not work with urllib not urllib2 ! im not too sure what to use if im going to deal with urllib2 cookielib ! can you maybe show me a fast example :)

Comment: Actually, if it's working on all of your browsers, it's a session. Meaning server-side, meaning you can't affect it. Try having python look through that HTML to find a new link that you can try. That's about all you can do.

Comment: well that it is what i have been doing but still not joy ! thanks anyways

Comment: Mhmm. Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but not everything always works out :)

Comment: it is gonna work out, i got 3 days of nothing but this, so it is going to work out ;)